# How to use access arrays dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using jQuery 1.7.1 (but that's probably irrelevant).

I have several JavaScript arrays that are populated in several ways. The arrays, basically, look like this:

```
var TreeArray = [0,1,2];
var FruitArray = [4,5,6,7];
```

I have some links that have an item type and an item id:

```
<a href='?' class='Link' data-itemid='123' data-itemtype='Tree'>elm</a>
<a href='?' class='Link' data-itemid='789' data-itemtype='Tree'>walnut</a>
<a href='?' class='Link' data-itemid='456' data-itemtype='Fruit'>orange</a>
<a href='?' class='Link' data-itemid='111' data-itemtype='Fruit'>apple</a>
```

When the link is clicked, the ItemType and ItemID are collected and passed to the addToArray() function:

```
$Links.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ItemType = $(this).data("itemtype");
    var ItemID = $(this).data("itemid");
    addToArray(ItemType, ItemID);
});
```

Here's where the problem is. If the ItemType is "Tree", I want to put the ItemID in the TreeArray.  If the ItemType is "Fruit", I want to put the ItemID in the FruitArray.  Here's my function (that doesn't work):

```
var addToArray = function addToArray(ItemType, ItemID) {
    var WhichArray = ItemType + "Array";
    WhichArray.push[ItemID];
}
```

I will have quite a few different types of arrays, not just two. I will have quite a few functions.

So, how can I access these arrays dynamically?

Comment: "that doesn't work" - Why doesn't it work?

Comment: `data=itemid='123'` shouldn't it be `data-itemid='123'`?

Comment: not that it is the source of the error, but `WhichArray.push[ItemID];` should be `WhichArray.push(ItemID);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your arrays to be properties of an object and then you can access them dynamically by name:

```
var arrays = {
    Tree: [0,1,2],
    Fruit: [4,5,6,7]
};

var addToArray = function addToArray(ItemType, ItemID) {
    arrays[ItemType].push(ItemID);
}
```

---

As an alternative, if `TreeArray` and `FruitArray` were global variables, you could also access them off the `window` object like this without changing the array definitions, though I prefer the first implementation above:

```
// global variables
var TreeArray = [0,1,2];
var FruitArray = [4,5,6,7];

var addToArray = function addToArray(ItemType, ItemID) {
    var WhichArray = ItemType + "Array";
    window[WhichArray].push(ItemID);
}
```

This works because all global variables are implicitly properties of the window object.

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me, but it's close.  I change arrays[ItemType].push[ItemID] to this arrays[ItemType].push(ItemID) and it works well.

Comment: @EvikJames - Yes, that was a typo.  I've fixed it.  Glad you figured it out.  I actually copied that wrong bracing on `.push()` from your question.

Comment: The top part of your answer worked like a charm. I knew there was a great answer out there for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> "I will have quite a few different types of arrays, not just two. I will have quite a few functions.
>
> So, how can I access these arrays dynamically?"

Usually this means that the answer is to have an array-of-arrays, or an object-of-arrays, from which you extract the reference; this seems similar to what you're trying to do with `var WhichArray = ItemType + "Array"`.

You build this super-container up automatically as you create your arrays, or by giving all the arrays the same class and doing `getElementsByClassName`, or similar alternatives.

For example you could just do:

```
var clicked = {}; // looks like {Tree:[123, 789], Fruit:[...]}

// For each clickable link...
document.getElementsByClassName('Link').forEach(function(link) {
    // ... add a callback which says...
    link.onclick = function(this) {
        // ... to take the itemtype and itemid...
        var itemType = link.getAttribute('data-itemtype');
        var itemId = link.getAttribute('data-itemid');

        // ... and add it to our master dictionary
        if (clicked[itemType]===undefined)
            clicked[itemType] = [];
        clicked[itemType].push(itemId);
    };
});
```

**This is all the code you need**, total.

Answer (score 1):

You could place your arrays in an object and access them with `[]`:

```
var myObj = {
   TreeArray:  [0,1,2],
   FruitArray: [4,5,6,7]
};

var selector = 'Tree';

// Access the array
console.log(myObj[selector + 'Array'][2]); // 2
```

In action: http://repl.it/CJQ

Comment: The top part of your answer was close to my final answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not key up an object with the different item types?

```
var lists = {
  Tree: [0,1,2],
  Fruit: [4,5,6,7]
}

var addToArray = function addToArray(ItemType, ItemID) {
  var WhichArray = lists[ItemType];
  WhichArray.push[ItemID];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var WhichArray = ItemType + "Array";`

WhichArray will be a string, not the array you wanted.

you could use:  `var WhichArray = window[ItemType + "Array"];` instead

Comment: This isn't the answer I was looking for, but it was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options:

1) if statement (or switch case, if you prefer):

```
var addToArray = function addToArray(ItemType, ItemID) {
    if (ItemType === 'Tree') {
        TreeArray.push(itemID); // notice push is a function, don't call with []...
    } else {
        FruitArray.push(itemID); 
    }
};
```

2) store the arrays in some type of data structure (an array or object):

```
var arrays = {
    Tree: [0,1,2],
    Fruit: [4,5,6,7]
};

var addToArray = function addToArray(ItemType, ItemID) {
    arrays[ItemType].push(ItemID);
};
```

Comment: You first idea is terrible. That's exactly what I want to avoid.  Your second idea hits the nail on the head.

Comment: @EvikJames i agree, the if statement is not extensible at all.